# Hibernate mapping on partial composite key

Tags: hibernate, partial, composite

I have following table structure something like this, one to many and many to one 
mapped to one of the composite key.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "parent", catalog = "testdb")
public class Parent implements java.io.Serializable {

private Long fileId;

private Set<Children> children = new HashSet<Children>();

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "file_id", unique = true, nullable = false)
public Long getFileId() {
    return this.fileId;
}

public void setFileId(Long fileId) {
    this.fileId = fileId;
}

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "id.childrenIc")
public Set<Children> getChildren() {
    return children;
}

public void setChildren(Set<Children> children) {
    this.children= children;
}
}


@Entity
@Table(name = "children", catalog = "testdb")
public class Children implements java.io.Serializable {
private ChildrenId id;

@EmbeddedId
@AttributeOverrides({
    @AttributeOverride(name = "childId", column = @Column(name = "child_id", nullable = false)),
    @AttributeOverride(name = "childrenIc", column = @Column(name = "child_ic", nullable = false)) })
public ChildrenId getId () {
    return this.id;
}

public void setId(ChildrenId id) {
    this.id = id;
}
}


@Embeddable
public class ChildrenId implements java.io.Serializable {
private long childId;
private Children childIc;

@ManyToOne
public Children getChildIc() {
    return childIc;
}

public void setChildIc(Children childIc) {
    this.childIc= childIc;
}

@Column(name = "child_id", nullable = false)
public long getChildId() {
    return this.childId;
}

    public void setChildId(long childId) {
        this.childId= childId;
    }
}


Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Parents.class);
Criteria childCri = criteria.createCriteria("childrenIc");
childCri .add(Restrictions.eq("childId", childId));
```

when i try to use criteria to join the table, it fails.
Unknown column 'this_.childrenIc_child_id' in 'where clause'
org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute query

even i changed to

```
Criteria childCri = criteria.createCriteria("id.childrenIc");
```

it also fails.

Please help, thank you.

Comment: Please help me, how should i query with criteria. Thank you so much.